# There is no option to create a javascript in create option for unity 3d .Only showing the c# script

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

There is no option to create a javascript in create option. But in most of the youtube tutorials they are using the .js files .Is there any way to use js file. 
Is this issue occurs due to missing of any libraries.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unity 2017  no longer has a ‘Javascript’ option in the Create Assets menu. They had already removed the javascript option; but **all the support is still there**, and you will still be able to create new UnityScript files outside of Unity (for example, via MonoDevelop or etc).

Comment: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript says all support for JavaScript ended in 2018.2.  So as of 2 months ago you cannot use JavaScript in any Unity Projects after 2018.2

Answer (score 0):

As version **2018.2** JavaScript is **no longer supported**,  It would be best to learn C# if you want to use the Unity Engine.  There is literally no reason to use JavaScript over C# in Unity since Unity has deprecated it.

Source: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript (Has a link to the JS to C# converter right at the top)

If you really want to continue to write your scripts in JavaScript, there is a tool to convert your JS files to C# but I wouldn't recommend that approach, simply because who knows how long until that tool itself becomes deprecated. 
The last option to use JavaScript would be to use an older version of the engine...

Comment: Ok. But can give more details about converting the JS files to C#.

Comment: That link has the link to the converter right at the top.